Запуск jar на другом комьютере с другим конфигом
Ситуация следующая:
Мне нужно написать сервис на Spring Boot с использованием Kafka и MongoDB. Данные для подключения к ним находятся в config.json на сервере, к которому у меня нет доступа. По ТЗ мне нужно локально поднять у себя Mongo/Kafka и настроить конфиг для тестов. Потом собрать сервис в .jar и отправить на проверку.
Проблема:
После сборки приложения в .jar локальный файл с конфигом - application.properties - тоже будет упакован в .jar;
Путь к данным для подключения в config.json - mongo.database.;
Путь к данным для подключения в application.properties - spring.data.mongodb.;
Вопрос:
Каким образом мне указывать путь к данным через @Value(${}), если путь в локальном конфиге и в конфиге на тестовом сервере разные?
UPD:
Короче, пришлось добавлять класс, имплементирующий CommandLineRunner, брать путь к файлу конфига из аргументов командной строки, создавать в приложении класс Config и парсить полученный JSON в этот Config.
Дальше можно брать нужные пропы из этого Config объекта, как из обычного DTO

Вы можете при запуске указать несколько конфигурационных файлов, использоваться будут все из них. Для этого надо запускать jar файл так:
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,file:///home/user/config.json

То есть через запятую перечисляются все используемые конфиги, первый из них - это ваш конфиг по умолчанию application.properties находящийся внутри проекта, второй - внешний конфиг.

С этим нет проблем. Вопрос в том как быть, если в config.json путь к данным выглядит так: mongo.database_name
А в application.properties вот так: spring.data.mongo.database
Дело в том, что через application.properties нельзя подключиться к базе данных, если не указать полностью путь spring.data и т.д. А на тестовом сервере стоит конфиг, в котором другой путь

Вы же какой то один путь использовать собираетесь. Ну и используйте переменную с тем именем, что вам надо. Или поставьте условие что если той переменной нет - использовать другую.
